# VIM - how to paste search register without special characters?

Tags: regex, search, vim

In insert mode, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> (see `:h "/`)  will paste the contents of the search register. However, if you search for a word with <kbd>*</kbd> and paste the search register, it will put in the special word boundary characters `\<` and `\>`. Or, if you're lucky, you might get '`\Vsearch`. I think this is silly, but I'm sure VIM has its reasons for making my life harder. How would I go about getting the contents of the search register without special vim magic characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search register may contain no (simple `/foo` search), few (`\<cword\>` search from * command), or a lot (`^\%(foo\|bar\)\w\+!\?`) "special characters". For the first two, there's usually a single match, for the last, there can be many matches.

Initially I've used a mapping that filtered away the special regexp atoms, but then I've written a more general [PatternComplete plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4248) (just published), that provides insert-mode and command-line mappings to insert the match(es). It also allows you to enter a regexp and then insert all matches.

Comment: Checking out now! But you should put it on github or bitbucket. vim.org is just the worst. Vimballs are also the worst.

Comment: You can consume it via http://vim-scripts.org/ (once it got synced, takes some days). vim.org is the canonical repository; it could need some love, but it's functional. Volunteers welcome :-)

Comment: Hi @IngoKarkat. I'm only interested in the case where the search register contains `\<` and `\>` chars. Is there an easy way to handle just that case without having to install the complete plugin?

Comment: @mroavi: You can try this: `cnoremap <expr> <C-r>& substitute(@/, '^\\<\<Bar>\\>', '', 'g')`. It just removes a leading `\<` and trailing `\>` from the current search pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want the search register to contain anything else than *exactly* the previous search pattern? `@/` contains the pattern, not the match.

If you do `/\Vfoo*bar` it's normal and expected that you get `\Vfoo*bar` in the `/` register. Same for `/foo\*bar` where you'd get `foo\*bar`…  The point of the search register is to be reused for further searches and substitutions: if it contained `foo*bar` instead of `\Vfoo*bar`, you couldn't do `n` or `N` or `:s//baz` which would make everyone's life a lot harder.

Since there is no `verynomagic` option you can set in your `~/.vimrc` I guess that you could do a substitution on the content of the register before pasting it.

```
fee faa foo*bar baz bam
/\Vfoo*bar<CR>
:reg /<CR>
\Vfoo*bar
:let @a = substitute(@\, '\\V', '', '')<CR>
"ap
foo*bar
```

Maybe you could create a mapping that does the substitution and the pasting in one go.

But I have a hunch that what you *really* want is to reuse the matched text, not the search pattern. If I'm right, see [this tip](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Copy_search_matches) for a possible solution.